# Which language is used to upload or start a website on internet?

Tags: html

Guys I am not studying web designing in a college/academy. So all you are my instructors. I have learn the basic html and css. But I don't know how to make a website active on Internet. I wish anyone of you answer me all the procedure.

Comment: you should read this at once before asking question.[READ HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a webhosting provider, that's a place where you put a code. Then buy a domain (it means that people can find your site by name.domain - like "stackoverflow.com"). Next step is to learn how to upload your content to a server like an ftp protocol using ftp client like Filezilla for example.

If you just want to publish your html/css website online and don't want to pay for anything, you could start a github page https://pages.github.com/.